How to share azure VHD across different subscription
We're deploying VM's using a template in Azure.In the template the image used is from blob url stored as VHD. I have made some changes in the VHD and saved it as a new blob. Now, we want few people test this vhd. I've read about Azure compute gallery, but can't make out how I can share this vhd. In AWS an private AMI can be shared by giving the account ID to share with. Is it possible to share via Azure compute gallery or is there some other means by which it can be shared.


How to share azure VHD across different subscription

To share VM images using the Compute Gallery, follow the steps below

Create a Compute Gallery with the desired sharing method. Follow the MS Docs for more details.


Once you have created a Compute Gallery, create a VM image version by navigating to VM > Disk > Create VM image version. Follow the MS Docs for more details.
Create VM image version


Once you create a VM image version with the definition, the definition will be added to your gallery as shown below.

To create a VM with the same configuration, open the definition, and you will have the option to create a VM with the same VHD.

To share the image definition with other users in a different subscription, you can assign roles as needed. Follow the MS Docs to learn more about compute gallery roles.

Note: To access the Compute Gallery, make sure that all subscriptions are part of the same tenant.



Once you assign the role to a user or group, only those with the assigned role will be able to access the Compute Gallery.

Thanks for the detailed reply, but my requirement is bit different. Is it possible to share a vhd through ACG? As I am deploying the VM using the vhd, so I want it to be shared with a particular user?

The Compute Gallery is a feature that stores VHDs, allowing you to directly create a VM using definitions from the gallery. You can assign roles to specific users to access to the Compute Gallery.

I'm new to Azure, so not getting "assign roles to specific users". What I understand is create a new user/external guest user (by invite), assign role to the user? Will that user be able to login and create vm using the shared ACG resource.?
Hope am making sense.

Yes, Create/invite a user and assign a role that user, so users can create a vm from compute gallery

@VenkatV in the 3rd image you've captioned "Specify the existing same VM details" from where to get these info?

Existing VM details, Navigate to VM overview JSON option, there you will get those details.

@VenkatV do you have any idea, how to deploy vm using an ARM template, image reference from the compute gallery. The gallery is in a different resource group and the vm in a new rg.
I will create another topic, if you can provide any info.
